# Is it possible to group config & ignore files into a folder in a React project?

Tags: node.js

When creating new React project, there're always a lot of config files and ignore files in the project root directory.

e.g. `.gitignore`, `.eslintrc`, `.prettierrc`, `eslintignore`, ...

Is there any way to group those files in to a folder under root?

Answer (score 0):

No, since the relevant tools look for those files in that place.

Prettier does know how to read configuration from within `package.json`, though, so that would be one file less.